# Get date part only of DateTime in comparing dates

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I am trying to select data from my table on or before a given time in my parameter.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT Expiry_Date FROM Table1
WHERE Expiry_Date <= :dateParam AND Expiry_Date > sysdate
```

The problem is dates on my table with data such as 14-NOV-13 03.01.45.362000000 PM which has a time part of more than 12.00.00.000000000 AM are not being returned in the result. So that if I enter 14-NOV-13 as the parameter, the data with 14-NOV-13 03.01.45.362000000 PM is not being returned.

How could I just get the date part or try to floor function the date column in my field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either in Oracle.  `trunc` works on date times:

```
where trunc(Expiry_date) <= :dateParam and Expiry_Date > trunc(sysdate)
```